# Binary Classification: My model classfies most data (95%+) as label 1

Tags: classification, cnn, class-imbalance, binary-classification

I am working with ECGs and trying to use a CNN model to perform binary classification. The goal is to classify 30s ECGs to detect a specific disease. I am using CNN and converting ECGs to images (scalograms). Unfortunately, the amout of with the specific disease are not enough thus I am plannign to split the 30s ecgs to multiple 10s ecgs (overlapping) becuase I have a larger dataset with 10s ecgs thus I can train my model.

I have trained my model on a dataset and tested on a different dataset that has 10s long ecgs. The model perfomed well. Eventhough, that the 10s dataset has a ratio of 1:9, I have created a balance training dataset and then tested on the testing dataset. The model had a good F1 score.

However, when I tried to classify 30s ecgs using the method described above most of the data are classifies as label 1 (diseas detected) and almost none as label 0.

PS: I convert the ecgs to RGB images (scalograms), which give information about the time-frequency domain
PS 2: My dataset is about 90% of images of label 0 (both 10s dataset and 30s dataset) however, when tested on the 30s dataset most of the data are classified as label 1. Need to mention that when trained I carefully choosed data to create a balanced dataset for training.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your 10s records skewed toward one of the two classes? If so, which class and in what ratio?

Comment: Unfortunately as with every medical dataset, the dataset was imbalance. So my dataset consist of multiple normal ecgs, then some ecgs with the disease I want to detect and then some other types of diseases. I have converted it to binary and by including the other types of diseases I allowed my model to become more flexible. I made the trainng dataset balanced but the testing dataset had the rest. Howver, it reached a high accuracy (relatively) of close 80% in the testing dataset.

Comment: What’s unfortunate about imbalance? // What is the imbalance ratio on the 10s ECGs? The 30s ECGs?

Comment: For the 10s ECG, in the training dataset I had a ratio 1:1 and in the testign dataset I had a ratio 719:4419. In the 30s dataset the ratio is 822:2500. However, when classifying in the 30s dataset, almost 98% of the data are labelled as 1 and barely any are labelled as 0

Comment: Why does the test dataset have imbalance while the training dataset lacks imbalance? Are you using some kind of artificial balancing to remove imbalance from your training set? [Good statistical methods dispute that imbalance is a problem in need of solving in all but some fringe cases that your scenario does not appear to be.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) // Let’s set  aside data manipulations you’re doing and if they’re wise. In all of your 10s records, what is the ratio of the two classes?

Comment: I am sorry my bad, I havent explained it well. I havent used any artificial balancing method. So in my 10s dataset I have 2768:20547. In th 30s dataset it's even worse and I dont have the exact numbers right now.

Comment: Would you like to contnue our discussion in a chat?